# how to call a view file from controller(cakePHP)

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.1

I am learning cakephp from few days ... so please help a bit thanks .

I made a controller --

```
class PostController extends AppController {
var $name='Posts';

function index(){
    $posts=$this->Post->find('all');

    $this->set(compact('posts'));

}
```

in view had post folder with index.ctp file . I want to ask from where it gets "CakePHP: the rapid development php framework" and from where it takes content . I send this data from controller so it  prints only `var_dump($posts);` ... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cake php has default layout files in folder "app/view/Layout" .. file name default.ctp in this folder will be taken as default ..

if you open default.ctp in layout you will see something like

```
<h1><?php echo $this->Html->link($cakeDescription, 'http://cakephp.org'); ?></h1>
```

and other links defined ..you can comment the and check what changes you get in view.

here is from where view gets ""CakePHP: the rapid development php framework"

this line

```
<?php echo $this->fetch('content'); ?>
```

in layout fetch the data from controller to show in view which we set using $this->set() in controller

if you want to change the layout create your own in layout folder 
and use in contoller like

```
class PostController extends AppController {
var $name='Posts';

function index(){
$posts=$this->Post->find('all');

$this->set(compact('posts'));
$this->layout = false; // ot you can set ypur own file like 'xyz' for 'xyz.ctp'
}
```

to set layout for each action in controller use

```
 function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->layout = 'layout';
 }
```

To learn more about layout see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#layouts

Hope you got me

Comment: yes it works .. but can u please tell we had to write in every controller function $this->layout = false; ...

Comment: ok that means if we don want layout to do $this->layout = false; in beforeFilter function.

Answer (score 0):

**"CakePHP: the rapid development php framework"**

For above look inside `views -> layout -> default.ctp` file.

Also change default `cakephp routing` so you can see posts index action when you have posts in URL.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to call a layout from controller is

```
$this->layout = 'Your layout page name';
```